# Notification on edit of downvoted content

Tags: feature-request, edits, downvotes, notifications

I just came across a comment by someone who wrote that they make a point of revisiting content on which they have cast a downvote. I really like the idea of checking whether stuff that I downvoted on has been edited so that I can remove the downvote.

However, afaik there is no support from the system for that. I need to revisit those questions/answers on my own steam, and if I forget, I forget.

So here is my idea:
Add an automatic notification (like the ones for comments on my own questions/answers) whenever someone edits a question/answer that I have downvoted.

This would help us to encourage (new) users to actually correct their answers by quickly removing downvotes when they have fixed a problem with it.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c it is marked [status-declined]

Comment: @ChrisF Ah, thanks for the link, I'm not yet used to the split between meta stackoverflow and meta stackexchange so that question escaped my notice. Pity it's been declined, I wonder why.

Comment: @ChrisF: And that poor decision should be reviewed and corrected.

Comment: It was declined [4 years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/1751/2). Sometimes it can be useful to revisit old ideas, especially given how much the site has changed over the years. Also, **I would only be OK with this feature if it was opt-in, and I could control the frequency of notifications (instant, hourly, daily, etc.), and I could also control the method of notification (on site, email, etc.).**

Comment: While not a notification, you can see this information under your "votes" tab using the "[Show Edited Votes](http://stackapps.com/q/6755/29529)" user script.

Comment: Same thing just happened to me too. I've retracted my downvote on a question because it was edited from a blob of unreadable text into a worthy question with all the details needed to provide an answer. That got me thinking about the same idea, but I think @GolezTrol's answer is a better solution for that.

Comment: Does recently implemented “Follow” button solve this request?

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim It's one half of the way. It certainly allows me to get notified. Nevertheless, I still need to remember to click the "follow" button whenever I downvote. I would definitely prefer a way to *automatically* follow my downvotes. Either by a general preference that I can set, or by some pop-up dialog that appears when I click the downvote button. But, yes, the "follow" feature does allow me to achieve what I want. I "just" need to remember to do it...

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim Actually, no, the "follow" feature is not what I want: It triggers on any comment that's added to a question/answer. This creates a *lot* of noise when all I want is to see *edits* to the downvoted content. Because I'm only ever downvoting based on the content of the question/answer, and unless that content changes, I will not reconsider the downvote.

Answer (score 104):

I'm in favour of this idea *in theory*, but I feel that an active notification would be too noisy and might come across as the system nagging you to rescind your down-vote even for the most trivial of edits.

What might be a better solution could be to have a page/tab on your own profile that lists the posts edited since you cast your vote(s).

You could then *choose* to look at this information or not, and then act on it or not. There would be no nagging from the system, no noisy inbox, just the the data for you to use or ignore.

Comment: will be this idea implemented?

Comment: Make it optional? I wouldn't mind the feature.

Comment: [Also on SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1752/170949)

Comment: Imho the combination of such a list, and and additional notification only for edits to downvoted closed questions would help. The reopen queue is short, so a responsive action by downvoters on edited questions could help clarify the current quality more quickly.

Comment: Make it so you get a ping just like chat when you have that page open?

Comment: Noisy or not, it's the only push method the system currently provides. Maybe with a way to opt in / opt out - e.g. "watch" the question ([which is a wanted feature is its own right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118899/is-there-a-way-to-get-notification-on-stack-overflow)) - but nothing else would satisfy the requirements.

Answer (score 37):

Good evidence can be found in the vote to reopen queue that such notifications would be sent for pointless edits. I frequently see posts in this queue that are still suffering from what caused them to be closed in the first place. They have been updated with edits like:

1. The OP changed the punctuation in their post.
2. The OP added an assertion that their post does not suffer from the problem pointed out by the people who voted to close (an assertion is not an explanation and thus fails to convince and is pointless).
3. Updated their question to say their problem has been solved.
4. Etc.

I have no reason to believe that notifications for downvoted questions that have been later edited would somehow not suffer from this.

Now, if the system could tell me when I check my stats and visit the list of questions I've downvoted whether they've been edited since I've downvoted them, this would be a different matter because this feature could be ignored. It would not be invasive like notifications are.

Comment: Yes, I agree that many edits would probably be worthless. Probably that's a matter of preference whether one is willing to look at 10 worthless edits to find the one that really improves the answer. My preference would be to take on the 10 bad edits to encourage the one who has improved his answer. I wouldn't mind some other, less invasive means of displaying this information. My trouble is, that I just don't get the information which of these answers *have* been edited.

Comment: I definitely like the idea of being able to have a separate page that I could optionally visit to check on edited posts, rather than being notified of edits.

Comment: I would like to see a way to check for edits to posts I've downvoted, and having a separate place for that would work. However, I don't see getting notifications of pointless edits as a downside. IMO when I downvote I'm taking on a responsibility, and people that don't want to bear that cost, who simply downvote and forget, probably shouldn't be downvoting. Annoying those people out of casting downvotes seems like a good thing to me. I want downvotes to be of high quality too.

Comment: I often see the opposite, questions in the close queue which have been edited already, e.g. added the missing code and error description. Unless the close voters left comments, you can’t even see whether the close votes happened before or after the edit. There are good chances that the questions are closed by robo reviewers anyway. Seems, users are better off deleting their downvoted/closed postings and creating a new one…

Answer (score 17):

I found this question because I was looking for this feature too. I don't think notifications are a good idea, but since there is an overview of votes in your profile page, it would be great if votes are marked there. For instance when a question/answer is modified since the vote, display that line in a different color, or with a small icon or label, so you can see that the post was edited since your vote.

Nice to haves:

- If edited after vote, show the date/time of the last edit.
- Be able to sort by that time too.

I would certainly have a peek now and then to see if there are any recent changes to posts I downvoted. After all, I downvote if I think a post is of low quality, but I'm happy to retract that vote if the post is improved.

Answer (score 3):

Inbox notifications is currently the only push channel that SE provides. So - noisy or not - nothing else would satisfy the *"notification"* requirement.

Unsatisfactory edits are an issue. From my experience, only about 1 of 5 or so is satisfactory (maybe even less). So not even grouping of entries related to the same post (that is already being done) would help here - some way to filter the posts is needed.

Possible ways that I see:

- explicitly show that you wish to be notified of the question's progress ([a wanted feature in its own right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51254/can-i-get-notified-of-changes-to-a-selected-question))
- use "tells" that the post's quality has improved in addition to the fact of edit to send a notification:

  - a closed post was reopened, or
  - a review to close it was completed with "keep open" (dubious - downvotes are intended to be an alternative to close), or
  - an answer has been posted (any or maybe upvoted/accepted), or
  - voting dynamics has changed