# Notification on edit of commented question

Tags: feature-request, edits, comments, notifications

I agree and wholeheartedly endorse the idea of notifciation for [edited down-votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/notification-on-edit-of-downvoted-content), but I have a more useful suggestion to offer:

**Notify me when a question I've commented on is edited.**

The purpose of comments is to "ask for more information or suggest improvements."  A notification upon edit would have two beneficial effects:

- An incentive to keep comments less chatty and more focused, and you'd know when the answerer addressed the issue you raised.
- An incentive to make edits and improve an answer, by allowing those who comment to revise their moderation and delete an invalid comment after the issue was addressed.

Comment: Disagree. That will result in too many notifications for frequent commentators. I generally write comments with brief answers because I don't have time to write a complete answer. If a user is really interested in the question, they can mark it as a favorite. And invalid comments can be flagged for removal, the existing system takes care of them.

Comment: Would love to see this feature. Often I comment on a question that doesn't contain enough info asking for more info, but then I never get to see the info when the OP does edit it.  To answer all the complainants about information overload; default it to being off, and let people who want it enable it via Preferences.

Comment: Not sure why this question is downvoted , it's a perfectly valid feature request. Just because you would not like to have the feature request actioned doesn't mean that the post should be downvoted.

Comment: @MattMcNabb voting on feature-requests express agreement/disagreement - it doesn't mean the post is bad or invalid in any way.

Comment: @vba4all have you got a reference for that policy? it seems to me that it'll just lead to the question being decided by the first 2-3 people who see it.

Comment: @MattMcNabb sure read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): `On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.`

Comment: @vba4all OK, I guess I need to start a meta thread about the meta..:)

Answer (score 2):

I agree but allow it to be opt-in. Put a little speech bubble icon below the Favourite Star and when I click that it will notify me when the OP edit's their question.

Comment: And maybe add another option to get notifications for answers / comments too.

Answer (score 0):

*Completely* disagree. I receive far too many "notifications" from Stack Exchange already. At any given moment, there are three or four things that are highlighted, glowing, and counting upwards in the top bar. Thank god they aren't throbbing, pulsing, or bouncing.

Send your users too many notifications, and they'll just ignore them. Or worse.

Notifications should be be limited to things that are *directly actionable*. Comment notifications, for example, are okay, because someone is directly responding to your comment. However, the team has gotten this wrong with pushing notifications for every upvote received. I can't do anything about it, so why should I get a notification each time that my reputation changes? I think it's a major contributor to the angst about downvotes, and I think it needs to go away. But *certainly* we don't need to add any more notifications.

It is not just a philosophical problem. I feel confident it would lead directly to users like me *not* providing suggestions in the comments when they otherwise would, just to avoid the nagging notifications.

What *would* be acceptable, however, is a list or other queue where you can go and see these questions if you are interested in them. You could call this a "notification" of sorts, but it isn't really one because it doesn't nag you.

The truth is, if I wanted to carefully watch a question that I commented on, I can already do so without assistance from a new feature. I can leave the tab open in my browser, I can add it to my browser's bookmarks, or I can star the question as a "favorite" on the site itself. A list of such questions is stored in my profile, complete with a visual indicator when they have been active since I last visited them.

Comment: We say comments are for "suggest X".  If an edit is made that resolves your issue, **REMOVING YOUR COMMENT** is the appropriate action.  And yet there's no assistance, whatsoever, in doing that.  Which leads to chatty comments with the occasional moderator nag.

Comment: +1 for the idea of the queue. It would IMHO be much more beneficial than expected for all these small things that happen on SO that you could be interested in but don't want as a notification. Like an event log.

Comment: but do you really bookmark a question which is bad ? which then got edited to good .