# "notify me on edits" option

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

I already came across these questions asked in meta

1. [Notification on edit of downvoted content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252055/3928375)
2. [Notification on edit of commented question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269587/3928375)

I accept one of the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269595/3928375) given for the second question (i.e) [Notification on edit of commented question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269587/3928375)

which states that

`Completely disagree. I receive far too many "notifications" from Stack Exchange already...`

I could realize the amount of notifications sent to a community members with **higher reputation** as even their older posts are **found useful for many and upvoted**

if that's in case, **why not "an option to notify on edits" to be added to the posts?**

```
     user can 'tick it' if the he wants the notification of edit
        or
     let it go
```

consider a scenario where an user posts his own answer for his question, as none of the suggested options of other community members came handy. and posts answer and thanks like..
[image]
[image]

```
#the images are just a sample edited screenshot not meant to specify anyone...
```

consider the commented member upvotes and appreciates the respect given by the questioner to the effort of other community members.

if the question is edited as...

[image]
[image]

the comment remains the same...

and I have noticed in several posts there are certain **irrelevant comments mentioned** and after being in this community for a while I realized that **the posts have been edited and the comments left as it is...**

will **an option the to notify the on edit** be beneficial or is there any other cure for this???

Comment: @Cerbrus this is about `adding an option to notify` if the question is edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[N](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272326/2140173) [o](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269595/2140173) [p](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269587/notification-on-edit-of-commented-question/269595#comment83730_269587) [e](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252059/2140173).

First of all

> I thank everyone for their time and effort

should never be a part of an answer. It doesn't answer the question and it's pretty much redundant. If you spot that feel free to cut that out of the answer.

Secondly, the comment:

> +1 for the last line

should never be posted as it's too-chatty. If you spot one just flag it for removal.

Such minor things just add noise to the question/answer, are redundant and just increase the amount of moderation we have to do afterall.

Comment: +1 for that first line. (And 'cause I agree with the answer, mostly ;-) )