# What to do with code related questions without code

Tags: discussion

I'm viewing quite a number of questions with questions asking for what doesn't work with my code/with what I'm doing, but without showing any code. Each of these questions has, after a few moments, a comment underneath like "Please show us some code".

Can't there be a better solution or should all these questions be flagged?

Comment: We put the comment there to be nice. Next most common comment: "What doesn't work? It doesn't work is not a problem statement." Of course, we wouldn't have to do that if people would just post better questions...

Comment: Yes, that's true. Everytime the same, not understandable how one can expect a good answer on very bad questions

Comment: I usually vote to close, leaving a comment that says something along the lines of "It's impossible for us to debug code you have not included in your post. Please [edit] and add the *relevant* portions of your code if you'd like us to help you find the problem."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have at least *15* rep, I would flag the question.

Under the `Flagging > Closing > Off Topic` section there is an option for:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

This sounds like a perfect situation to use this flagging option.

If you have at least *3000* rep, you have the ability to close. This same option can be found in the close menu under `Closing > Off Topic`.

Comment: I'd like to add that I'd consider it fair to retract the close vote if, after a suitable time, one notices the question is edited. (Which one is [not notified of](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269587/notification-on-edit-of-commented-question).)

Comment: @Jongware I agree. Although I as your linked post points out, this may be hard for frequent commentators.

Comment: You only have the ability to _vote_ to close unless you have been granted the Hammer of Death to Duplicates privilege. My experience with flagging is that is seems to annoy the mods.