# Is asking for clarification on the meaning of a term really "Too Broad"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338786/what-is-a-single-abstraction-in-this-context) was recently put on hold as *too broad*. Is it really? I feel as if close voters treated it like a question that asks about "abstraction" in general. However, it asks to explain the term in a really narrow context, defined by the short paragraph the OP had trouble understanding. So there are not many possible answers, and because the context is quite narrow, I don't think that answers will be too long. In fact, my answer did fit into "few paragraphs", as the close reason demands.

Maybe the question is not exceptionally great, but it is about "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Rules of good software design are definitely unique to software development (although I've seen people applying them to robotics. But that's a topic for another discussion about formulation of this part of the help center ;) ), and it is practical - interpretations of these rules have direct impact on implementation.

I've seen this happening with other questions that didn't contain code, but were quite answerable and well defined. So, can we please discuss this in general, and perhaps consider reopening the question?

---

*Note:*  This is a different question than: [What to do with code related questions without code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275281/what-to-do-with-code-related-questions-without-code). It asks about questions without code, but regarding reasoning about code.

Comment: I would not see missing code as problem in general, but a question which makes it necessary to follow links to get a context are IMHO  off topic. Closing a question does not mean it should not be reopened if it was improved.

Comment: If I had encountered the closed SO question out of the context of this Meta question, I would have voted to close it as unclear, for the reason that bummi gave. Questions posted on SO should be self-contained: all the necessary pieces should be *in the body of the question itself.* Links are okay only for optional additional information. So while I'm not happy with "too broad" either, I would not reopen this question in its current state.

Comment: "In fact, my answer did fit into "few paragraphs", as the close reason demands." This is only because your answer was a partial answer, with phrases like "like in the other SO questions you link" and linking to wikipedia threads for the terms instead of explaining the terms. The question itself is still too broad and "good answers would be too long for this format." I would vote to close such questions I encounter as well.

Comment: @Unihedro The links are tangential. The point is that in the context presented by OP "single abstraction" means a "single concept" and that's it. Most questions on SO provide links to the terms they use should anyone be interested in *further* reading on the subject. They are not essential to the answer.

Comment: @Louis Fair point. I've added the whole paragraph into the question. Now it's self-contained.

Comment: @bummi ^ as above :)

Comment: @Unihedro And also, your argument completely misses the point. If any answer on SO wanted to explain in detail *all programming terms* it uses, they all would be too long for this format. We usually assume some common ground, but provide links 1) when it's not the case (i.e. some term is not understood clearly by the reader) 2) to provide some reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's too broad.

The topicality is borderline; this might make more sense on https://english.stackexchange.com/ or even https://ell.stackexchange.com/. That said, I'm splitting hairs; if the asker is struggling to interpret documentation then expecting him to choose a site based on whether his confusion arises from unfamiliar jargon vs. unfamiliar English implicitly expects him to already know the answer; we're probably ok giving him the benefit of the doubt here.

Regardless, the asker did include enough information to make the question specific and clear (after a bit of help editing). If it's specific, clear and on-topic, that should suffice in most cases. I'm glad to see it was reopened.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and for fixing the title - indeed it's much better now :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a question about a general non-specific topic that, although surely tied to software design, is not actually tied to a particular design problem.

I have no issue with codeless design questions if the poster has a specific requirement or problem for which possible solutions can be presented, but questions such as that linked are more suitable for a computer science site than SO.

Comment: Well, but IMHO the point is, that the topic is not general, because of the narrow context. It's a short paragraph in the linked website, perhaps it should be put into the question, but it is not general.