# Asking the same question again, but with different words

Tags: support

I asked a question on stackoverflow section and it got down voted, I didn't describe the problem very well. Would it be against the rules if I deleted it and asked again? But with more clarification?

Comment: Why not edit/clarify the question you already have?

Comment: @MartinJames to be honest I felt a little embarrassed  because it got down  voted several times

Comment: Down votes are often misunderstood. I've personally written questions (when I was new to Stack Overflow) that were downvoted, after reviewing helpful comments from other Stack Overflow users I edited the questions to include the requested information and clarify as necessary. This can actually cause "Make-up upvotes", where users will see a downvoted question that the OP has shown effort to improve and in turn upvote just to get it back to 0. Remember that a downvote is -2 but upvotes on questions are +5.

Comment: Sometimes you get stuck in a hole because your question gets voted down, and you can't type quickly enough to recover from it. This is particularly a problem when you make an edit, but before you are finished someone else edits your question. In this case my opinion is it is best to delete the question, and start again. The community can sometimes be quite hostile about this however.

Comment: I personally believe the functionality of down votes needs to change.  The minimum score one should ever have is 0.  Nothing less.  If its a question that currently has a score of 3 and it gets 4 down votes it should only go as low as 0.  The negative numbers drive people away, here is a prime example.  It psychological, even if you tell people "Well negative means they dont agree so dont worry"...that doesn't help.  Other better answers will always propogate to the top with a positive point balance...but the worst answer should only go as far down as 0.

Comment: @JonH People with questions are not really a scarce resource that we need to worry about running out of because downvotes scare them away. The scarce resources are: people who want to answer good questions; people who ask good questions. If no questions ever went negative there would be a lot more spam/junk, discouraging answerers from slogging through it all. We don't want to forbid you from asking questions just because you asked one badly, but we do want to encourage you to ask better questions.

Comment: @amalloy - And my answer to that is you still can, but you don't have to allow an answer to go in the negative to accomplish your goal.  If what you mentioned was the case, than I propose that comments too should go in the negative.  See my point?  Why does one go below 0 but the other doesnt.   If I see a comment I don't care about on Stackoverflow I leave it as is..I cant downvote, and I surely don't want to upvote it..so it sits there...lonely.  But to a good answer will yield a positive score and that moves to the top automagically.  So if we have 0's sitting at the bottom so what...

Comment: cont...I'd rather have the user base and the good emotions than a bunch of people quitting and leaving the site because they were marked with negative points.  And there are 100s if not 1000s that have felt this way and have probably left.  A simple google search will show you that many have fled because of this misunderstanding.  There is no good reason to go in the negative...not one solid reason that makes sense to me.  I've heard the well we'd have a lot of noise and well we just need the user to understand that - does not mean wrong, it just means we dont agree...etc etc.  It doesnt help

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It's not against the rules. But it *is* a bad idea, for several reasons:

1. Some of the same users will see it the second time. They will not be amused.
2. Deleted questions make it harder to fix question banning, since you will lose access to them once they drop off the "deleted recent questions" link in your profile. The downvotes still count against you on all questions, deleted or otherwise.
3. If you didn't figure out how to fix it the first time, you'll probably just get downvoted *again* (by the same users or others), which counts toward question banning again.

Instead, **edit** the question. Editing will

- grant you fresh exposure on the homepage
- allow downvotes to be retracted
- not count toward question-banning
- show those who see your question again that you're making a sincere effort to improve

All this is especially true if your original question was also closed, since closed questions count toward the question ban, but the first edit made within five days of closing will automatically put the question in the Reopen queue so users with 3000 rep have a chance to vote to reopen.

Comment: Whilst these things are all true, I think I'm right in saying that _most_ people browse the 'newest' questions per tag, because otherwise there's a vast amount of 'noise'. So opening a new question might well be the best way of getting an answer. (But that doesn't address the downvote on deleted Q problem, as you note). I know it's gaming the system, but I would suggest leaving the 'bad' question deleted and asking a new - better - question. Provided you don't do it often, question banning isn't a problem.

Comment: "allow downvotes to be retracted" --> How often does this happen? I do this occasionally on questions with missing code or error messages (the "this isn't working"-questions) when I leave the tab with the question open. But most bad questions I downvote the vote is fire and forget. (I know, that is an old problem here on SO). For the rest I agree with this answer.

Comment: Would be nice to get a notification if a question you downvoted gets edited.

Comment: @Sobrique have you any usage data that support that? I am definitely using the active tab and the RSS which also shows the active ones.

Comment: anecdata and observation only.

Comment: @Sobrique: that is, at best, very *risky* advice. If someone noticed the question was re-posted like that, and flagged it for moderator attention, a moderator could well be inclined to delete the new copy, undelete the old (perhaps with the changes copied over) and tell the OP to get on with it.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets I agree and find it odd that this isn't already implemented here on SO. Not for all edits, but for when the OP edits the question.

Comment: Yea, not all edits i agree,  only op edits or edits that are approved by op.

Comment: @OcasoProtal: Most downvotes are fire and forget, yeah, although if you leave a comment in reply to critiques, those usually will have a chance to remove their downvote, as well as an downvoter who sees the changed question. The rate is not what it could be, but it's non-zero.

Comment: @DanielStorm: Well, edits on downvoted answers could be as useful...

Comment: @MichaelDibbets http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252055/1157054 and it's SE equivalent: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/192171

Comment: @MichaelDibbets: I wrote [a script to dig through posts you can retract your vote on](//stackapps.com/questions/6755/get-a-list-of-posts-youve-voted-on-that-have-been-edited)!

Comment: Nice :-) that'll help

Comment: I don't think notification of edits is a good idea, even if by the OP. Some users have thousands of votes and would get flooded by it. Moreover, the downvote is a reflection of the post at that time, and if content is posted which does not meet the proper criteria it deserved a downvote. Users are not required to follow up on the state of other user's content. That said, I think the script idea is interesting, and perhaps it would make sense to have a page you could visit somewhere, or perhaps a search option, so that if inclined view a list of posts you downvoted which were OP edited.

Comment: I had a post which got down-voted. A user commented with suggestions to improve my post. I did the requested improvements. The user further commented based on the improvement and added "Sorry I can't retract my vote-to-close." So what I understand is that there are different types of downvotes, some of which cannot be retracted. What's the reason for that?

Comment: @bli: Votes to close are not downvotes and do not change the score; they are votes to [close the question to further answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). They *can* be retracted at any time until the question is closed (and at that point can be replaced with votes to reopen), so if this happened in the last year or two, the user was misinformed.