# Negative votes and question improvements: Is it OK to repost?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

I posted [a question which got negative votes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40789601/1878788). Based on the comments I received, I tried to improve my question.

However, I fear that due to the negative rating my question now has, there is less chances my questions will attract answers.

I believe my question truly deserves answers.
Is it OK to repost the improved question as a new one in order to get more attention?
If so, should I delete the original one?

Comment: But ... it has an answer ...?

Comment: You ask multiple questions, and your first question is primarily opinion based... unless there is an objective definition of "elegant". It is currently eligible for close votes for the reasons "Too Broad": too many questions asked, "Unclear": it is unclear which question you want answered, and "Primarily Opinion Based": elegance is not an objective criteria.

Comment: The question has an answer, but that did not fully work for me (more precisely, the answer revealed another problem). Besides, my question contains a sub-question for which I'm genuinely interested to get more relevant answers. I  guess I should decompose my question in several ones in order to get answers to the various points.

Comment: Highly related and possibly a dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303253/asking-the-same-question-again-but-with-different-words

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In an ideal world the edits you made will attract upvotes and answers to your question - so you've done the right thing.

However, we don't live in an ideal world.

If you question has no, or only one zero scored answer, then you can delete it and repost it. There's nothing built into the system to prevent it. If you can't delete it then reposting the question is definitely frowned upon. We even have a moderator message template that covers question repetition.

However, if you do decide to delete and repost you must bear in mind a couple of things:

1. Other users may remember seeing your original question and think "hey, didn't you just post this?". If so, expect comments and even downvotes. This may not appear fair, but that's the way things are.
2. Deleted and downvoted questions count towards the automatic question block. Do this too often and you'll find yourself in a situation where you can't ask any more questions for a while.

Your best bet is to avoid getting into this situation in the first place. Take more care over asking questions:

- Don't ask as soon as you have a problem, try to work it out yourself. Build a minimal solution that demonstrates the problem *before* you post your question. This may well lead you to the solution so you don't have to ask.
- Write your question out in the "ask question" box but **don't** press "post". Read the other questions that the system suggests might be similar to yours. You never know you might get the answer from those.
- Monitor your question closely during the first few minutes. Respond to comments with edits to the question to improve it. That might help stave off the downvotes so you don't get into this situation again.

Comment: _only one zero scored answer_ is still someone's effort.