# People should get notified when answers to their questions are edited

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, edits, notifications

I really think this is a good idea. I think there would be situations where a person asks a question, gets an answer and say "Oh that doesn't really help. I am gonna ignore that". But then the answer gets edited and really solves the asker's problem but the asker doesn't know because he/she is not notified! He/she has to wait for another answer to come and then see the change of the first answer!

I know people usually comment on their answers like this:

> Edited. See if this can help you
>
> See my edited answer

Or something like that. It would be great if OP can get notified when the answers to his/her question is edited.

---

Furthermore, if a question gets edited and all the answerers of that question should get notified as well. They can check to see if their answers really answers the edited question. Isn't that great?

Comment: You are very probably not the first one coming up with this idea. Sure there is no dupe?

Comment: I don't think so. I looked at the suggestions when I ask the question and I looked at the similar questions column. There is no such question. @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Similar to this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/notification-on-edit-of-downvoted-content

Comment: If you can't bother coming back to the question you asked to actually read the answers, why should the system notify you an *answer* has been edited?

Comment: But lots of times I make minor edits to improve small things. Notifying the asker could be not worth it, or even annoying. Maybe there could be a checkbox to say whether the edit is minor or not (like in wikipedia).

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: I assumed Sweeper meant "ignore" as in "not upvote, not accept".

Comment: I *know* that on meta, downvote on a feature-request means "I disagree with this feature." But I still really hate to click it. For the record: I don't think we should do it, but the suggestion is perfectly *reasonable* and clearly expressed.

Comment: If the proposal was just for the *questioner* to get notified - rather than competing answerers I'd be for this.

Comment: @Sweeper I think you should separate your two proposals - getting a notifrication when an answer to my question is modified or when a question to which I gave an answer is modified ***is not the same thing at all***...

Comment: I am so very certain I have seen this exact title before....

Comment: Here's one dupe on Meta SE http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97740/optional-notification-on-an-edit-to-an-answer

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That's a little bit ridiculous. If you know you received an answer or two, and you already read them, and then nothing happens for a while... why would you keep checking everyday just to see if someone decided to edit an answer? Do you check on all the questions you have asked, everyday, just to verify that? Wanting the system to notify you when an answer has changed is not in any way a sign of you not caring about the answers to your own question.

Comment: If I make an edit to an answer which is significant to the OP (or someone else) I ping them in a comment. Perhaps a rare benefit of perusing low-volume tags is that my favourite-tags filter always shows when other peoples' answers have been edited :-)

Comment: @Sweeper excellent idea. This has happened to me quite often when I had to randomly go back to the question to find that an edit was made to the answer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This definitely should be done, as posts editing follows the *idea* of Stack Overflow, where answer should be not a forum post, consists of the main post and a thread of comments, but a solid post contains complete answer.

For a long time I am following this paradigm, editing posts in response of comments, instead of engaging in a discussion. And I think this attitude is very good for the site's purpose. Yet it's bad for the OP, as they get no notification.

This definitely will never be done, because there are A LOT of people hunting for reputation with pointless grammar fixes, which will produce a lot of noise.

As a trade-off, it could be made to notify only the op, only if the answer was edited by its author. Which will resolve both T.J. Crowder's fears and noise from pointless notifications from serial grammar editors.

A very good suggestion were added in the comments, which worth even a separate answer, IMO. If we don't trust "Do not notify the author" (AKA "Minor edit") checkbox, why not to add an opposite "Notify the author" one? A concerned editor would likely press this one.

Comment: If the answer is not edited by the original answerer there could be a check box "notify the asker".

Comment: @Dialecticus Actually, I personally like that idea even if the edit is by the original author.

Comment: On the other side, once this feature is implemented, serial grammar editors will be frowned upon a lot more, making them stop.

Comment: This reasoning makes no sense. Only low-rep users can gain reputation when a *suggested edit* is accepted, but suggested edits *cause* a notification. In other words, the edits made by people who edit for reputation cause noise while only edits made by users who don’t earn reputation for edits are silent.

Comment: I wondered today if OP gets notified if I edit an answer and found this thread. Since I see a lot of subjunctive in your answer, may I ask if any of this has been realized in the meantime? Otherwise, this post could be featured as hot meta-post.

Answer (score 21):

I think the way it is now, where people have to intentionally do the notification, is probably for the best. With automatic notifications, I think we'd be getting too much noise along with the signal. We'd also have the problem of getting both an automatic notification, *and* the questioner/answerer posting one as well. (People will do that; we all use the system without quite understanding all the various things it does, to a greater or lesser degree.)

Separately:

I think it would be difficult and error-prone to create an automated system that doesn't suck. I've answered nearly 10,000 questions on SO. Do I want a notification every time someone fixes a tag or typo or grammar in any of those questions? I do not. Jon Skeet's got me beat by more than a factor of 3. Does he want those notifications? I suspect not, but we'd have to ask him.

So then we have the "Minor edit" checkbox [Oriol mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306419/people-should-get-notified-when-answers-to-their-posts-are-edited?cb=1#comment249221_306419). But will people tick the box? Consistently? No, they won't.

So *then* we get into "Well, maybe only in the 24 hours since the question was asked." but then people have to understand *that* mechanism and force the notification when more than that much time has passed. ("Hey, why didn't Joe get the notification when I edited? He did last time.")

So *then* we say "Well, we can show a note above the Edit Summary box to tell them whether notifications will occur." Will they read it? Consistently? No. People don't read.

Maybe we could eventually get there, and maybe I'm wrong that it's not worth the time. But I'd rather see that development time spent on, say, making Stack Snippets (dramatically) better, creating better heuristics for preventing "my question is in another castle / your answer is in another castle," flagging and pushing previous questions that likely answer what someone is typing, and so on.

Comment: Is there a good post listing all the ways stack snippets (the client-side HTML+CSS+JS-kind we have) should be improved (best excluding "make it a clone of $other")?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I don't know of one, and there probably should be one. There are plenty of feature requests going unloved, though, such as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239706/add-a-console-to-stack-snippets). Then there's the fact that the editor gets in your way and scrolls at odd times; half the time when you click Show Snippet it mysteriously unshows itself; the list of scripts to insert is dramatically limited and constantly out of date (latest jQuery 1.x is 1.11.1; 1.11.2 was released 9 mo ago, currently on 1.11.3); the editor is painful to use and underfeatured; etc.

Comment: [This one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299236/feedback-requested-code-editor-and-stack-snippets), whenever it gets done, would probably improve things in general, though not adding the console asked for. (Though not keeping the list of current library-versions up-to-date.)

Comment: I see your point. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, The "minor edit" checkbox will be better than nothing. Wikipedia seems to do fine with that one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think we should look differently at the two proposals: I agree with you as an answerer (I don't want to be notified every time a question I have answered gets edited). But I would like, as an "asker", to be notified when an answer I received changes because that change may be useful ***for me***. You answered 10k times but you only asked 15 questions and your noise argument is less obvious if we restrict the scope to those only...

Comment: @assylias: Yes, I feel the same way. There are people who ask thousands of questions and almost never answer, so it's one issue for them; and there are those who answer thousands and almost never ask, so it's a different issue for them. The two really should be separate.

Comment: I think most of your objections to this can be managed. To many notifications from minor grammar fixes? Just notify when OP edits the post. Double notification if OP also posts a comment? Remove the edit notification if there is a comment notification, so there are no duplicates. Still to many notifications? Create a setting where you can opt out of receiving them.

Answer (score 8):

I think a better idea would be to give the user an option to choose whether he wants others to get notification while making an edit or not. for example a user changes his Answer should have an option saying "Notify OP of the edit", if checked only then the OP should get a notification. Similarly if OP edits his questions, he should be able to control whether he wants everybody in the answers to get a notification or not because not all the times the edits are likely important ones in terms of information they might be more of formatting/tagging relating etc.

Comment: And the text description of the option would read "Was your edit substantial, or did you just fix spelling/formatting which you shouldn't?"

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to propose a modification, or perhaps a clarification to the OP's proposal.  Add a notification *on the page* so that if you are visiting the page, you see that something happened (sort of like the "1 new answer to this post" box you get when you are viewing a page, and somebody answers) but don't spam the contributing user's inbox with a notification.

Comment: *when you are viewing a page* So if you don't open the question you never get notified?

Comment: @tripleee I think that your proposal is a great compromise. Sometimes you might not notice that an answer has been modified and this feature would be very helpful.

Comment: @A.L That's right. This fixes the immediate pain of having to add a comment saying "I edited my answer; please reload the page" but avoids the inbox spam which many commenters here regarded as problematic.

Comment: @tripleee I don't understand how it works when you have hundreds of questions, how do you know which one to open?

Comment: This proposal does not help for that scenario at all.