# Notice about the fact that my answer was updated

Tags: discussion

If I posted my answer and after some time I decided to improve it, and have updated this answer - will the author of the question receive a notice?

Comment: No. But [it has been proposed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306419/people-should-get-notified-when-answers-to-their-questions-are-edited).