# Should I edit the original question, or delete it and ask a new one?

Tags: support

Apropos of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464225/can-i-store-polygons-in-my-database-and-have-them-be-edited-by-the-user):

After further research and some more thought, I've realized that what I'm really asking isn't  *"Can I store polygons in my database and have them be edited by the user?"*  But rather something along the lines of:  *"What is the best way to store JavaScript data inside of my Rails database?"*

Should I delete my question, or should I edit it? (Changing the question completely)

Comment: No votes and the one answer doesn't seem to be extremely useful (from my glancing and the comment left by someone else) so I'm not sure it would hurt anything to fix it up and make it more concise to what your actual problem is. If you do, I'd update the answerer to let them know.

Comment: If your question is *"What is the best way to store JavaScript data inside of my Rails database"*...any answer would be opinion based and so the question would be **OFF-TOPIC** and so liable to closure,...are you sure you want that? As it stands it's likely unclear or too broad and equally likely for closure.

Comment: As @Paulie_D points out, it would be off topic.  I'm just going to delete the question.

Comment: @Paulie_D It's not outright off-topic. He could still specify "best" in a sense that is not opiniated like "fastest speed", "lowest amount of memory", ... This can be made on-topic if only more specifics about the actual problem are given.

Comment: I agree with @Trilarion . In fact if the question would be "How to store JavaScript data inside of my Rails database?" it could not be seen as off-topic and odds are multiple possibilities would be given. It's a matter of phrasing I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting aside the actual content of your question for a moment and speaking strictly from a general and wide point of view, your best interests conflict somewhat with SO policy on this subject. I see it as a byproduct of real-world human nature vs. the best intentions of an esoteric world.

If you have received a good deal of downvotes and/or vote-to-close(s), your best option is to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) then delete your question and rewrite it into a new question that follows SO policy. Do a complete rewrite; changing the title or a few sentences without changing the overall tone of the question is going to get you nothing but a repeat performance with more bad mojo coming from the people who recognize it as an equally lame copy of the original.

There is no reminder¹ for people who DV'ed/VTC'ed to come back to a question that has been revised to review their vote(s) and it is unlikely that they will.  In a magical rainbow unicorn world they are supposed to but that simply does not happen on a regular basis. If you edited your question into something appropriate for the 'question-of-the-month' award you might receive a few upvotes but even that voting is going to be skewed by the previous voting stats.

So even with the best intentions and good-as-gold revisions, your edited question is going to receive a restricted audience. Many users disregard negative voted question altogether and some that do look at them do so with the sole purpose of adding to the downvotes.

Personally, if I recognize a question that has gone through a major overhaul for the better, I will certainly retract my VTC and reverse my downvote. I often even double-reverse the downvote with an upvote. I also know from experience that my actions are in the minority as I rarely see the DV or VTC count change beyond my own retraction(s). Perhaps others do not see the revisions the same way I do but I tend to think it is much more likely that they never see them at all.

In reality, copy the original and any meaningful information from the comments and delete it. Rewrite your question into something that you can be proud of and resubmit it. Keep in mind that this isn't a 'keep trying until you get it right' world. Make sure you get it right the second time around².

You might also want to consider that your question may not be right for SO at all.

---

¹<sub>[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request): [Notification on edit of downvoted content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252055)</sub>

²<sub>What constitute a 'good question' is an evolutionary concept on SO. A high-voted question question from several years ago is very likely a crappy question now. Look at **recent** comparatively high-voted questions for examples of how to formulate your own; don't try to imitate a high-voted question from yester-year.</sub>

Comment: `There is no reminder for people who DV'ed/VTC'ed to come back to a question that has been revised to review their vote(s) and it is unlikely that they will.` But there is a Reopen Votes queue, and edited closed questions go into it. While reviewing Reopen Votes, I often come across questions I closevoted in Close Votes queue.

Comment: @Gothdo - good point; I've found some the same way but I have to admit that the ones discovered are a small percentage of my total downvotes. I 'discover' many more by their replacement to the top of the forum queue.

Comment: Edited questions get bumped to the front page. However, most SO regulars _don't_ view the front page, it's _far_ too busy (although the front page can be manageable on the less bust SE sites). Instead, they are following their favourite tags. And they'll only see the bumped questions if they are viewing the "active" tab, they won't see them if they are viewing the "newest" tab.

Comment: FWIW, when I log on to SO I check the questions I responded to on the previous day for interesting activity. I occasionally see replies to my comments that the respondent didn't ping me with, but it's rare for me to see improvements to bad questions I DVed &/or VTCed.

Comment: Great points. I emphasize DELETE the old question. Often when I'm searching SO for a solution, I come across multiple versions of the basic same Q, from the same author. I suspect those were cases where the OP tweaked the question for any list of reasons. Frustrating.