# Stuck in post-ban

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, closed-questions, post-ban

Recently I have got an question ban because of (mainly) [this stupid question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303275/use-for-areas-in-rest-api?noredirect=1#comment71056375_41303275). I want to fix the question ban and, as expected, I have to edit the old question to get a change to get the question permission back.

The question was deleted so I undeleted it and [edited it completly](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41303275/revisions). But how in the world would I get rid of 7 downvotes? It is very hard to get a "lot" of upvotes so I would never reach that.

I bet that if I edit all my other questions, and lets say get all +2 votes I still would have this negative question and would still be banned from asking questions.

Of course I could edit the question to a new one, a hole new question, but I dont have one, so what would I do? Even if I would have one, only a couple of people would *see*/*click on* the question because it is vote closed.

**Question 1:**
How to get enough people to vote my deleted, -7 voted question, and get enough upvotes?

**Question 2:**
Is this not a problem in the system? A structual problem?

**For clearance**: I am not trying to let anyone get rid of this question ban (I know that is not possible), but maybe a solution for this problem.

Comment: *"because of (mainly) this stupid question"* No. It is a total quality assessment; it doesn't work based on a single question. Polishing this one turd isn't really going to help you get out of the question ban. Your edits improve the presentation of the question, but don't make it any better fit for Stack Overflow. It isn't likely to get any more upvotes. Focus on your *other* questions, the ones that were borderline and might actually get upvotes if improved. Is this a problem in the system? No, not at all. It is by design that people who *repeatedly* contribute unwanted content get blocked.

Comment: Servy, this is not a duplicate. I am not asking why, or how to solve this. I am asking if this is not a real problem.

Comment: As it is, your question is reasonable enough to vote to re-open, so I did that. However, it is beyond my expertise so I cannot upvote it with a clear conscience. Exactly for such cases – a downvoted and closed question that gets edited into shape –, it has been suggested to [get a notification](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/notification-on-edit-of-downvoted-content), so the downvoters could reassess it and perhaps take back their –1. Unfortunately (I imagine it would not be a huge bother) that proposal never made it.

Comment: @CodyGray And then my question ban will disapear? I dont have fait in that.

Comment: What do you mean "then"? If you have lots of highly upvoted contributions, then yes, your ban will disappear. One downvoted post will *not* cause you to be banned. A whole series of questions with a score of 0 or 1 is not promising and is the *real* problem here.

Comment: That is what I mean.. It isn't so difficult right?

Comment: @Arendax - You are currently not banned from asking questions. Next, I suggest asking good questions, answering questions and editing old ones to make them better. That way, there is a good chance of you not getting QBanned. Note that QBan is not "directly" related to downvotes i.e, if your total score on all your questions is -1, then it doesn't necessarily mean that you will get a QBan.

Comment: @TheLostMind now that I dont have a question ban anymore, is it bad to delete the question? Or do I need to edit it nevertheless?

Comment: @Arendax - If you think that the question is salvageable, edit it to make it better (by adding what you know, what you've tried etc).

Comment: @TheLostMind okay. Thanks for the advice.