# How can I get questions un-downvoted?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes, low-quality-posts, voting

Say I asked [some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41436690/6850771) [crappy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41580945/6850771) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41150916/6850771) (yes, I've done that) and they got downvoted (rightfully so).

Now say I edited them to provide an MCVE, or a clear problem statement, or whatever was originally wrong with them. Now I've got a (hopefully) good question on my track record, but with a lot of downvotes. This is quite the blemish on my reputation and profile.

How can I get un-downvotes (or upvotes) on these questions?

Comment: Light a penny candle. Burn an incense cone. Wait. Repeat...

Comment: When you edit your questions, it bumps them on the active page for a given tab, putting it up for further review.

Comment: You can only get enough upvotes by advertising.  Put a bounty on the question with the "reward existing answer" reason.  This can go either way of course, looking at the edits you did I would not recommend this strategy.  This is not just one question that produced a "blemish" btw, consider spending more thinking/debugging time on your problems before asking for help to reduce the odds for future downvotes.

Comment: You'll need time and exposure. If you've edited the hell out of it and are convinced they are OK now, consider sharing a link to it on twitter or all those other social media non-sense.

Comment: With the volume of new questions in many tags, many people don't have time/patience to consider any given question more than once.

Comment: @TinyGiant aye - and then it's burried by new content within 5 seconds ;-)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252055/1157054

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71440/badge-suggestion-responsive-aka-quality-control-adaptability-etc

Comment: @Mat'sMug depending on the tag, that is possible; but I frequent the JavaScript tag by the active page regularly, and I haven't seen that.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver: User name checks out.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In my experience, editing a question or answer rarely gets any downvotes reversed, even if the edit is a significant improvement. The downvoters have already left and don't get notified of your edits. Being bumped to the top doesn't really make a difference, either, because the people watching the active page aren't especially generous with upvotes.

Every now and then (maybe twice) I've gotten a downvote reversed when the downvoter left a comment telling me what was wrong. After I fixed the problem, I replied to their comment and then they changed their vote.

Pretty much you just have to accept the downvotes for now. If your question or answer has long term value, then it will gradually get positive votes over a year or two. That has happened to me many times.

Answer (score 7):

What I often do is start a bounty. The risk of that, however, is that some people will look at the number of downvotes, and just downvote the question without concern.

However, I have undone my downvotes easily with a bounty and it actually gave me upvotes sometimes.

Comment: It depends on the used tags. For niche tags, greats answers receive 10 to 20 upvotes, average ones 2 to 5 or even less.

Answer (score 7):

My experience has been that you can't reliably get people to un-downvote.

Bounties, meta posts, etc. *can* bring more attention and garner upvotes to counter the downvotes, but it's extremely unlikely that people will come back to the question and reverse their votes.

I've encountered a similar problem with close votes. For example: [How to inspect only new Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257474/how-to-inspect-only-new-java-code) The question initially was poorly worded/formatted (the information needed to make the question on-topic was only present in tags). The question was then closed and downvoted a few times (got to -4 at one point, I believe.) I stepped in and edited the question to try and put it back on track, which garnered some upvotes and brought the score back to zero.

I pinged one of the close voters asking them to re-evaluate the question, but I received no response and have seen no change on the question. This is just the most recent example of several. I occasionally go in and try to rescue a question that I think shows sincere effort, isn't a duplicate, and can be easily reworded, but this almost never accomplishes anything.

People also don't usually bother with re-checking duplicates. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257194/how-do-i-compare-parameterized-parts-of-an-array (and yes, I know that it was automatically closed)

I don't blame people. there are a lot of questions of dubious quality, and I can't imagine many people have the energy to go back and try and rescue something that they consider marginal at best, not when there's a lot of other things to do.

TL;DR

People don't come back and look at 'low-quality' questions. Therefore, you won't get many un-downvotes.

P.S. I would hope to avoid a big meta effect on the linked questions - those users didn't poke the sleeping giant, I did.

Comment: Just as a quick note, you can't ping close voters except under [specific circumstances](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), which that question didn't meet. I doubt whoever you pinged ever saw the question again, or knew you mentioned them.

Comment: Also, for your "dupe close" link, the "Community" in the closer list means the OP agreed with the the dupe and agreed to close it. (You might already know this, it's hard to tell from your wording. If you do, just let me know and I'll clean this comment up.)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with close votes, so both of your comments are apt. As for the duplicate one, I only knew that the community closure meant that it wasn't exactly normal and I wanted to acknowledge that fact.

Answer (score 3):

As I didn't see someone to voice it already here is my behavior:

Once in a while (every week or 2 weeks) I go to my profile -> activity -> votes -> downvotes tab and review the posts since last time I checked (color change when visited) to see if the downvote is still in line with the post.

Sadly, maybe 1 on 20 posts gets edited, and when they are they're rarely better than before (more details but still irrelevant, some more fluff around the question) so my vote stay as is. Sometimes it get even worse (ranting about the votes or comments) to the point where I cast a close vote.

So don't lose faith, votes on post is a long time bet, it can get upvotes on mid/long term if you really salvage it.

Comment: I do something similar, but with close votes, and I do it in order to follow my close votes with delete votes.

Answer (score 0):

Asking a good question is work: You have to reduce the problem, check whether the problem persists when switching to the latest release, maybe check the bug tracker, compile all the relevant information, try to identify not relevant aspects and so on.

Reading question is work: I have to read the question, try to understand it, estimate whether I am capable answering it, think about it and so on.

If someone with more than 1000 rep is too lazy to do his part of the deal, my part growth and I get annoyed. I have to ask simple stuff like the used version or to get a MCVE. For a newbie, this is to some extend acceptable, I can teach them and hope they will ask better questions next time. The downvote is a way to express my displeasure with your question. Even after fixing it, you asked a bad question and should do better next time from the beginning.

The downvote does not harm your rep, it's -2 per downvote. The upvote add +5, so you only need two upvote for five downvotes, which is fair for a good question, isn't it?

Comment: and only lose 1 from a downvote, still 5:1

Comment: Right, I confused it with the rep changes for answers.

Comment: @Yakk downvote loss is 2 not 1

Comment: @gnat [citation needed]

Comment: @Yakk it's right there [in the reputation FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269654/839601): "You lose reputation when:

    one of your questions or answers is voted down: −2..."

Comment: @gnat I stand corrected!  Huh, always thought question rep was half answer rep.

Answer (score -33):

You can just delete your downvoted question and create new one.

Comment: Does that remove the loss of rep? Yes. But it does not remove the down voted question from your account. Any 10k+ rep user can still see it and it is judged against your account.

Comment: Doing this a lot is a good way to get yourself into a question ban.

Comment: Also note that this won't help if you're _trying to get out_ of a question ban- At that point, you _can't_ ask new questions. Your only choice is to fix your old ones, or post so many answers and useful edits that the system eventually allows you to ask another question.

Comment: but it's a good hack :)

Comment: No, it is not a good hack? It is terrible practice. In the long run it really can mess up your ability to use the full features of SO. Any question, no matter how bad it is written can sometimes help others too. Just deleting because you've lost a little bit of rep is ridiculous.

Comment: This is going to get you into hot water with the moderators. Re-posting badly received questions is **not** something the community appreciates or tolerates much beyond a first offence. Then there is the automatic question banning system, where deleted questions **still count against you**.

Comment: I'm not using this practice myself, it's just my advice for others

Comment: @Alex And it's bad advice that you shouldn't be giving to others.

Comment: just interesting how many downvotes I'll get on this anwer

Comment: @Alex well considering your answer is basically "kids, this is how to properly shoot yourself in the foot"... what did you expect? No one wants to upvote this as this is terrible advice and shouldn't be given.

Comment: If I could down vote your comments, I would. That is how ridiculous this advice is.

Comment: why so serious? If somebody ask me how to get lot of money, my first answer would be: "You should rob a bank".

Comment: By this, you can be banded to ask a question.