# Letting receivers of downvotes ask why they got it

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting, downvote-reason

Yes, I have got downvotes on quite a few of my posts, and rightfully so, they were just bad. And yes they did teach me [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and stop being lazy and soon i started frequenting that page a lot, either before asking or before criticising (which also went a lot of way in making me better).

But I have received a couple downvotes on posts, that according to me were ideal and received upvotes by the community too. Even after editing downvoted questions and making them better, they [don't tend to get upvoted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344523/how-can-i-get-questions-un-downvoted). Even [good answers to bad questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23005/preventing-users-from-downvoting-good-answers-to-bad-questions) get downvoted. And quite a lot of times, downvotes are thrown willy-nilly and the downvoters don't offer an explanation as to why they are doing what they're doing.

Can there not be a system where the recipients of the downvotes can ask for a review from the downvoters? No, I'm not asking to unmask the downvoters, as that will start a really vindictive nature of "revenge" downvotes that none of us want.

What I am asking is

- After editing a downvoted question, there appear an option for redressal only visible to the OP. Upon clicking the option, it will automatically send a notification to all the people who had downvoted *before* the edit. Ideally, it should be a bot message with no personal 'touch' (of course, I mean fluff) by the OP.
- If the question has been downvoted and has no comments, even then there should be some sort of option so that the OP can ask the downvoters *without knowing them* and without making any edit to the question. For example, if Abe posted a question which got downvotes by Gabe and Fabe and no comments, after a day or two, Abe could select an 'explanation for downvotes' option which notifies Gabe and Fabe that the OP wants an explanation for the downvote. Also the explanation would be visible to all, where anyone (with obvious rep based privileges) can flag it if it was unsatisfactory. This way, Abe doesn't know who downvoted, Gabe and Fabe don't *have to* (but should) give an explanation, there can't be just any arbitrary explanation (to slide out of the next point) and there is a better system in place where the OP does not feel lost in the tide.
- If there is a serial downvoter, who is not commenting at all, or someone who is repeatedly ignoring the request for 'explanation of downvotes', or giving unsatisfactory explanations, they be put up for moderator intervention or whatever else the powers that be decide.

How feasible will the above be?

Comment: Can the downvoters of this post please explain themselves? _My poor attempt at humour_

Comment: this has all the smells of [Explaining down votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437/578411).

Comment: Although I disagree with most of your proposal, I would like to have a system that informs me when a question I down-voted (or just voted on) has been edited. Often my down-votes just stay because I never note that there has been an edit.

Comment: @BDL I think that has been requested before and the response was "Favourite it"

Comment: Can you explain where the research effort is in this question? There are hundreds of other questions in meta on this subject yet you reference none of them. Why then should the "this question does not show any research effort" on the tooltip need further explanation each time this question is downvoted?

Comment: Start that, and some veterans will just leave before they get swamped with these notifs. Most people who have used this site for a log time downvote way more than they upvote. Start such a system and their inboxes will be blowing up with these. And most of these veterans don't comment knowingly. So these notifications will just bother them, without getting the OP the explanation they want

Comment: Sure. How much do you suggest should charged for the review?  Should all the review fees go to the reviewer, or should SO get a share?

Comment: @BDL users would just uselessly-edit their posts to enable a notification.  Like so many suggestions on SO, it sounds OK until users actually get it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Oh hell no.

I don't want notifications for posts I downvote.
Not to mention "Moderator intervention" for people that ignore such notifications.

Downvotes are a ***anonymous, low effort*** quality control mechanism.
There's few enough downvotes being cast already. Let's not restrict that.

Besides, why should all of this be implemented *only* for downvotes? Upvotes on low quality answers is just as much of a problem.

Comment: Not only this but I feel that this would only benefit _good_ questions, which should be negated by the upvotes it would receive, most of the time bad questions are closed or need no explanation on why they've been downvoted.

Comment: I am not against downvotes at all, on the contrary, I believe  them to be essential. What I want to know how feasible if at all, are my suggestions.

Comment: @NissimR: Not feasible at all.

Comment: @yivi Very well, that is what I wanted to know.