# Are there special or reserved usernames?

Tags: support, comments, display-names, comment-replies

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3731896) answer's comments I noticed someone trying to ping the most recent downvoter with “@Downvoter”.

Does this work? If so, are there other usernames that do different things similar to this (”@Upvoter”, “@Flagger”, etc.)?

Comment: The dupe here explains *why* such as system won't work in addition to the implied fact that this feature does not exist.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. It's different in the fact that I'm asking if it works, not requesting a feature to have it work.

Comment: @Makoto Even though that question doesn't fit mine exactly, I guess the answer is sufficient enough to answer my question. Thank you for providing me some insight into why this isn't here.

Comment: It works well. It serves as an *obvious* indicator to moderators that the comment should be deleted on sight. These are noise. Don't post them. Ever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't "work" in the sense that this comment isn't delivered to the inbox of whoever downvoted.

Using this notation is just a way of commenting and hoping whoever downvoted will read the comments and address the comment directed at him or her.

Comment: I should consider posting a feature request to add this.

Comment: @JL2210 That likely won't fly. See [*Letting receivers of downvotes ask why they got it*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360963/2751851)

Comment: @JL2210 I doubt such a feature request would garner much support. Some of us use our votes freely and often and don't want our inboxes full of comments asking why "I want to foo the bar" with no code was downvoted...

Comment: Still, a person deserves to know why somebody thought their question/answer was bad (possibly so they could correct it).

Comment: @JL2210: the information would be helpful, sometimes, and if the poster takes the information in the right light (a *big* if), but it has nothing to do with *deserving*.

Comment: @JL2210 I stopped reading my inbox years ago.  Adding more unwanted gunge would just add to the 'inbox not worth opening' set:(

Comment: I suppose. I still want to know what's wrong with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642620/odd-behavior-when-using-inc-si and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640036/why-is-xoring-ds-not-allowed

Comment: @JL2210: The first one didn't provide a reproduceable example (until you edited it). This was stated in the comments below your question.

Comment: Good point. And the second?

Comment: @JL2210 before trying to ask for any "explain downvotes" suggestion please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin carefully.