# Reset negative vote after question has improved

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, review-queues, downvotes

Stack Overflow always recommends users to improve their bad questions. It can help users learn how to "ask a good question".

But even if the "bad question" is really improved, those who gave downvotes will not revoke their downvotes.
The questions with negative votes are often ignored - because negative votes mean that the question is bad and not worth your clicking and taking a look.

So, the question may be improved, but the asker may not receive valuable answers.

---

### How to?

When the user edits to improve the question, SO can provide the user with an option to "reset negative votes". This option will submit this edit to the review list. If passed review, the negative votes will be reset, otherwise they will not. Limit the frequency of users using this right to avoid abuse and harassment (1 time per week).

===============================================

Here is a suggestion to solve this problem from the perspective of Downvoter:
[Notification on edit of downvoted content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/notification-on-edit-of-downvoted-content)

This suggestion is from the perspective of asker.

The former may disturb the downvoter, and the latter may infringe the rights of the downvoter.
They are all for try to solving the situation where the negative vote questions is unpopular and improving the problem may not be useful. But I don’t think they can be considered as "duplicate".

Comment: How is the system supposed to determine whether the question has improved? Are you suggesting that if someone makes any change e.g. fixes some spelling mistake then all votes should be reset including upvotes? Everyone would just add a full stop everytime they got a downvote.

Comment: How should be decided if a question has been improved? Simply editing can't be enough to remove all downvotes. *those who give downvote will not revoke their downvote* - Yes, because most of the time they don't even notice that the question has been edited. Especially when the edit happens later on.

Comment: Your last "Off topic" block is completely unfounded. It does not bring good light to a question to suggest that the community members are unable to think by themselves, especially since no one can read minds. Consider rolling that back for the sake of the feature request.

Comment: @E_net4isoutofcommentflags It was indeed offensive, I have deleted it. But, giving downvote is much easier than talking with others!

Comment: You have already posted a feature request here. It doesn't sound reasonable to then assume most votes are simply bandwagon'd.

Comment: Maybe apply the same idea for close-voting too. Seems even more relevant there.

Comment: @E_net4isoutofcommentflags Based on my years of experience using Stack Overflow, once a question or suggestion is has bean questioned or downvoted, the participants tend to pick fault the question itself rather than help the questioner solve the problem or improve it.

Comment: @gnat This is another solution to the same "problem". They cannot be equal.

Comment: @Flithor 'giving downvote is much easier than talking with others' yes!  You get it.  Bad questions get a free downvote from the skilled and experienced engineers who give volunteer time to curation.  I, for one, would be only too happy to review questions that I downvoted and were later edited.  How much do you suggest I charge for reviews?  I would want, at least, $100 up front, non-returnable.  PayPal will do nicely, thank you.

Comment: Some meta posters have suggested review systems before, often expecting that curators to expend effort on endless, and often probably pointless, reviews for free, despite the implication that OP's are hiring the reviwers.  Such suggestions are utterly ridiculous.

Comment: I oppose this as described, but could be convinced to support resetting votes on a question that is *reopened*.

Answer (score 21):

No, let's not insult the few caretakes that still dare to cast down votes by having their votes thrown away.

Votes are my own. No one<sup>1</sup> gets to decide for me if my vote is no longer valid. If my downvote triggers an action to improve the question I guess that is a win and if that is a good improvement visitors might chose to up vote. That doesn't mean that a good improvement means my concerns for casting a down vote are addressed. If and when I revisit that post I might change my mind and undo my vote.

Let me re-iterate again (and again and again and again) because many new users to the network (and the many "followers/spectators/commenters" on Twitter, reddit, Quora, Medium, dev.to, private discords, [insert favorite Social Network /Chat here]) don't consider votes to be a content rating mechanism. If your argument is that votes should reset then all votes, also the upvotes, should reset. But it is hardly ever that suggestions in this context never want to deal with that aspect. They are happy with the upvotes, yet when it comes to the best signal to indicate something is off with a post, everyone wants to duck, hide, run, accuse, blame, whatever. And more often then not when it comes to down votes  the content is never blamed by the opposition, it is the down vote and in extreme cases the users that cast those valuable down votes are seen as the problem.

This really has to stop. Offer suggestions that instruct users how improve their content, use a similar  UX to "ask wizard" when editing a post with tips and guidance what and how to improve.

On Stack Overflow we want the content to be awesome for the next generation.That requires that sub-par content is downvoted to learn and indicate that the post isn't good enough according to some users. Taking downvotes away or resetting votes hampers that goal as you don't shield visitors from low quality solutions. It makes scripting the future for people who loves code harder.

---

<sup>1. except obvious abuse cases where either the voting reversals script or an SE staff member invalidates my votes</sup>

Comment: I welcome any reasoned rebuttals. I must admit, you are right.

Comment: While I agree with this answer, I wouldn’t mind a private review queue, that contains contributions that had been edited since I issued a vote.  Keep it in this private queue for 48 hours to keep it small (or shovel the order daily).

Answer (score 16):

This simply isn't feasible. Besides being open to abuse, it isn't fair to allow some subset of reviewers to invalidate other users' legitimate votes.

You only get one chance to make a good first impression. You have an *infinite* amount of time to get the question right *before* posting it.

Comment: "If you can't ask a good question, then you should not come to SO." right?

Comment: @Flithor I wouldn't put it that way. But you should not be surprised when low-quality questions get downvotes. This is the whole point of a downvote: to signal a question that is unclear, not useful, and/or does not show research effort.

Comment: You won't put it that way. I also admit that SO has a lot of bad quality problems. But criticizing newcomers is not a good community culture. SO has always been like this. SO community members are offen telling newcomers by action: Get out! **Maybe the chat room is more suitable for newcomers.**

Comment: It has nothing to do with newcomers. There is absolutely no prejudice here against newcomers. Low-quality questions get downvoted (and *should*), regardless of how new the asker is to the site.

Comment: @Flithor It is part of a _professional stance_ to be open to feedback and constructive criticism. This is even listed in the code of conduct, and new users are not exempt from abiding to it. If people insist on hardwiring this idea that moderation is harmful, we cannot help with that. As explained in the other answer, by letting people ask low quality questions, you would be harming the experience of thousands of users over the feelings of a single new user.

Comment: @Flithor It's not just newcomers I even saw 50K+ rep users getting downvotes and a newcomer getting 20+ ups(This question was from R tag and was even in *hot network questions*. It's just the community's way of telling your question/answer is lacking something. And it's useful for future readers to segregate good answer from bad answers.

Comment: @CodyGray sure, that's right...But some downvotes are really confusing

Comment: @Ch3steR - I'd go further. My subjective experience is that when a newcomer posts a high-quality question they are likely to get a slew of up-votes. Gee, it's almost as if the community is *happy* to see a newcomer that contributes good content, and doesn't have anything against the newcomer status.

Comment: @Flithor 'But some downvotes are really confusing' what about the inexplicable upvoting on really terrible questions?  We should require review and explanations of those too, (actually, I can explain some of them as robo-random upvoting to cover up voting-ring and puppet fraud).

Comment: @MartinJames - Don't forget the vpvotes from those "helpful" individuals who set out to "correct" the "harm" done by others downvoting.

Comment: A year later, at least I am glad to see that the SO community has a higher tolerance for bad questions from new users - downvote and initiate delete without left any comment is not common now.

Comment: @Mr.Squirrel.Downy I have seen people ask excellent questions as their first question, and I have seen people use the site for 14 years and continue asking bad questions. Nothing about one's level of expertise with a programming language inherently prevents asking a good question - but there are fundamental *diagnostic*, *problem-solving* and *research* skills that we expect everyone to have.